# How to generate generic parameter types using method.param() via Sun's codemodel?

Tags: java, generics, code-generation, sun

I'm looking to generate a signature in a generated constructor containing generic parameter types. The output will look something like this:

```
public Constructor(FooA fooA, FooB<FooC> fooB) {
    super(fooA, fooB);
}
```

constructor.getGenericParameterTypes() will return Type[], but in order to populate the method's parameters via method.param(), I need to pass in a type of JVar.

I'm thinking the code generator will look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pt.length; i++) {
    if (gt[i] instanceof Class) {
        constructorMethod.param(pt[i], s);
    } else if (gt[i] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        constructorMethod.param(gt[i], s);
}
```

where pt is a call to getParameterTypes() and gt is a call to getGenericParameterTypes(). Except that constructorMethod.param(gt[i], s); is an illegal statement because method.param() will not accept parameterized types and I am unable to cast parameterized types to classes.

What is a better way of generating signatures with generic types?